# How to use a string as an object with diferent parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of post that is call test and the next code takes other array and push the post if the name equals something:

```
var test = [];
docs = [{name: 'mateo',lastName: 'mateo'},
        {name: 'Jhon',lastName: 'smith'}}]

docs.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.name === 'mateo'){
        test.push(item);
    }
});
```

I want to use different parameters for the name, but I don´t know how, I was trying to use something like this but it did´t work:

```
var test = [];
docs = [{name: 'mateo', lastName: 'mateo'},
        {name: 'Jhon',lastName: 'smith'}}]
const varNames = ['name','lastName'];

docs.forEach(function(item) {
    for(i = 0; i < varNames.length; i++){
        if(item.[varNames[i]] === 'mateo'){
            test.push(item);
            console.log(varNames[i]);
        }
     } 
});
```

Comment: Please update your post to include a complete, runnable example.

Comment: Replace `item.["varNames[i]"]` with `item[varNames[i]]`

Comment: If i use [varNames[i]] i get a syntax error when running nodejs ( I get an error with ["..."] too, I don´t know how to make that work is the problem.

Comment: @ManuelEsteban does `test` already have elements in it before `forEach` is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how bracket notation work. Change

```
if(item.["varNames[i]"] === 'mateo') {
```

To:

```
if(item[varNames[i]] === 'mateo') {
```

By the way, you should break the loop once an item is matched:

```
if(item[varNames[i]] === 'mateo') {
    test.push(item);
    break;
}
```

You could also replace that whole `for` loop with another array function called `some`, so that your whole code looks like:

```
docs.forEach(function(item) {
    var check = varNames.some(function(varName) {
        return item[varName] === 'mateo';
    });
    if(check) {
        test.push(item);
    }
})
```

Which can be shorter if you use an arrow function:

```
docs.forEach(item => {
    if(varNames.some(varName => item[varName] === 'mateo')) {
        test.push(item);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you the some() method for arrays is the solution to my problem.

Comment: @ManuelEsteban You're welcome! BTW, the `for` loop works fine too, you just need to correct the syntax of the bracket notation and add the `break` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this, everything will be easier:

```js
let docs = [
  {name: 'mateo', lastName: 'johnson'},
  {name: 'Jhon',lastName: 'smith'},
  {name: 'Mark',lastName: 'mateo'}
]

var test = docs.filter(item =>item.name === "mateo") 
console.log(test)
```

Then to check for an array of names you can simple use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if some of the properties match:

```js
let docs = [
  {name: 'mateo', lastName: 'johnson'},
  {name: 'Jhon',lastName: 'smith'},
  {name: 'Mark',lastName: 'mateo'}
]
const varNames = ['name','lastName'];

var test = docs.filter(item => varNames.some(name => item[name] == 'mateo'))

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to iterate over both `varNames` and `docs`. You're familiar with `.forEach`, so this example uses it, though this may be a better case for `.filter`.

```js
const test = [];
const varNames = ['name', 'otherName'];
const docs = [
  { name: 'mateo' },
  { name: 'name' },
  { name: 'otherName' }
];

varNames.forEach(varName => {
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    if (doc.name === varName) test.push(doc);
  });
});
console.log(test);
```